# Python timedelta replace 0 time with string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, timedelta

I have many time records in a column that look like:

```
  Time 
 0 days 04:19:03      
 0 days 00:25:28     
 0 days 08:15:03 
 0 days 00:00:00
```

There are a few 00:00:00 time records mixed in with my time entries. I'd like to replace them with 'incomplete'. But I'm unsure how to do so and doesn't look like a common use case from what I've searched. I've tried the code below but it doesn't seem to recognize 0 days 00:00:00 to replace as the value stays the same. I'm assuming this is because timedelta isn't a string, but I'm not quite sure how to set up.

Some code:

```
df.loc[:,'total_time'] = df.loc[:,'time_total'].replace('0 days 00:00:00','incomplete',inplace=True)
```

Comment: ah ok i have edited the post to do so

Comment: Do you want to use this column as a pandas TimeDelta or keep it as a generic object?

Comment: the column is currently formatted as pandas timedelta, if its possible to keep as timedelta but replace the 0:00:00 with 'incomplete' that would be ideal. but understand it may not work like that, as long as the other time formats are maintained i think that a different data type would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is I'd make sure your `'Time'` column is of type `Timedelta`

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

Then you can use `mask`

```
df.mask(df == pd.Timedelta(0), 'incomplete')

              Time
0  0 days 04:19:03
1  0 days 00:25:28
2  0 days 08:15:03
3       incomplete
​
```

Comment: perfect! good to know about the mask function. this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pandas timedelta objest. Like this: `pd.Timedelta(0)`